# DocxTemplate ignores jinja tags in Word doc

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using DocxTemplate Python lib to generate doc.
My word doc has a table with two column and I use the same jinja tags on both columns. DocxTemplate successfully replace the left column with the paga but ignores right and returns blank.

I'm out of idea why it behaves that way. Please see the screen shot

My word doc:
[image]